# Django library for Stack Exchange API authentication?

Tags: django, stackexchange

I'm writing a webapp that heavily uses the StackExchange API. I'm currently using OpenID authentication but given the only people that will use the site will be SE members, I've been wondering if there's a library for Django (or Python, in general) that can handle the login process for me.

I'm specifically thinking of something that slots into the process like the `django_openid_auth` project does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). The supported authentication providers are:

- Facebook (both OAuth2 and JS SDK)
- Github
- Google (OAuth2)
- LinkedIn
- OpenId
- Persona
- SoundCloud (OAuth2)
- Stack Exchange (OAuth2)
- Twitter

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for signup/login process as it supports Stack Exchange OAuth2.

Since your app heavily uses StackExchange API, you should consider using [Py-StackExchange](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange) along with `django-allauth`. Please have a look at [FAQ](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/wiki/FAQ) and it's [API support](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/blob/master/api.yml) for StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

You have Py-StackExchange, perfect for using from Python. Check out [the code at GitHub](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange) or [its page at StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python).

---

### Added after Oli's comment

For managing login/registration there are some good working projects. You can read a good review of 4 of the most common libraries at hackerluddite. [Django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) and [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) are likely the most complete, stable and used.

Comment: Yeah it's fine but has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: Yep. Sorry. I've added that on my answer.